# How do I make production access to Firebase impossible during local development?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, reactfire

Humans make mistakes.

While I'm developing my web application using the Firebase Web SDK, providing emulators using `connectFunctionsEmulator` (for example) a bar appears at the bottom of my web app showing me that I'm using an emulator:

[image]

Well, `reactfire` [requires me](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/reactfire/blob/main/docs/use.md#initialize-product-sdks-and-register-them-with-reactfire) to use production credentials before I can connect to the emulators. At least the API key. [The same seems to be true for the Firebase SDK to begin with](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize).

In fact, the message itself is a bit misleading. It means production data (passwords, real names etc) shouldn't be inputted on the web app as it would be transmitted over HTTP ([source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2773#issuecomment-733930698)).

This is somewhat comforting, since I really don't want any part of the client to interact with production while I'm in the middle of feature development. However, I don't think it's enough.

I want to make it such that it is impossible for me to access production from the development frontend without dismantling failsafes, and for this to carry over by default to other engineers on my team.

Is this possible at the application level?

### What I've tried

- HTTP Proxy

This works as expected. I'd prefer not to have to use a proxy if possible.

- Content Security Policy headers

I could be wrong, but everything I read and know about CSP is that it only works for static assets such as images, scripts, and stylesheets. I don't think it'd work for HTTP requests, right?

- Web Conditions in Chrome

This doesn't allow requests to `localhost`, so it's no-go. Also, it wouldn't carry on to others on my team.

- Turning my wifi off

This works too. Not really portable, though, and worse than just using a HTTP proxy.

Comment: As the warning says, just don't use your production credentials? I don't see what's so hard in _not_ reaching your production database? Don't connect to it, and don't use your production credentials, that's it. I'm confused, what am I missing?

Comment: That's a good question, and I realise I've left out crucial details: the SDK I'm using for some reason requires a valid API key and credentials _before_ connecting to the emulators. I'm using `reactfire`; I will update the original question.

Comment: Doing some more reading, it looks like Google always suggests using `initializeApp` with credentials before emulators can be connected. The API key is always required. From my understanding, it's "production is hit if emulators are not set up" which seems a bit dangerous.